# WebClient.UploadValues Duplicate Key

Tags: forms, post, request, key, webclient

I am having a bit of difficulty proxying a request on my site.

In theory, this should work

webClient.UploadValues(url, "POST", HttpContext.Current.Request.Form);

Unfortunately, the form contains a duplicate key "elemKey"

When I use HTTP Analyzer and look at the post data it shows that key three times, with three different values.
Parameter Value

elemKey value1
elemKey value2
elemKey value3

Unfortunately, the call the webclient makes shows the key once, with a comma seperated list of values, which does not work.

Parameter Value
elemKey value1,value2,value3

I tried creating a NameValueCollection from the HttpContext.Current.Request.Form variables and adding the multiple elemKeys, but it again, just concatenated them together with commas.

Is there a way I can create this request in the manner I need?

Thanks
-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used UploadString instead of UploadValues and all is now well

string html = webClient.UploadString(url, "POST", HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.ToString());